# Не выводятся шоркоды в кратком описании блога wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, visual-composer, шорткод

Приветствую. Есть сайт на wordpress, где некоторые элементы в записи: в частности онлайн-видео, слайдер выводятся с помощью шорткодов. Подскажите: почему на странице блога, где выводятся их краткие описания (с помощью visual composer) - не работают выводятся и в таком виде: `[embed]https://vimeo.com/channels/cooking/122874495[/embed]`, `[rev_slider blog]` ?

Пробовал использовать в `functions.php` и:

```
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'shortcode_unautop');
add_filter( 'widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'shortcode_unautop');
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'do_shortcode');
add_filter( 'term_description', 'shortcode_unautop');
add_filter( 'term_description', 'do_shortcode' );
add_filter( 'comment_text', 'shortcode_unautop');
add_filter( 'comment_text', 'do_shortcode' );
```

и различные комбинации

```
apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );
do_shortcode( get_the_content() );
```

Но все равно тоже самое...

Дополнено. вот так выглядит вывод файлов шаблонов:
1) vc_mad_posts_slider.php

```
<?php $post_content = mad_post_content_truncate(get_the_content(), 100, " ", "..."); ?>
<?php if (!empty($post_content)): ?>
    <div class="entry-body <?php echo (esc_attr($animation)) ? "animate-left-to-right" : "" ?>"><?php echo $post_content ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

2) vc_mad_blog_posts.php

```
$post_content = !empty($entry->post_excerpt) ? 
$entry->post_excerpt :   mad_post_content_truncate($entry->post_content, 
mad_custom_get_option('excerpt_count_big_post') , " ", "…");
echo $before_content;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подобное поведение шорткодов, как правило, объясняется тем, что при выводе контента они не обрабатываются.
Для того чтобы решить эту необходимо осуществлять вывод контента с помощью функции [do_shortcode](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/).

Судя по всему, в данном случае для вывода контента эта функция не используется.

Comment: я использовал различные связки `do_shortcode` или у вас есть еще что-то предложить?

Comment: я все правильно понимаю - вы так имели ввиду? `add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', do_shortcode( '[rev_slider_vc]' ));` но, не срабатывает..

Comment: do_shortcode используется при выводе контента (в документации по ссылке в ответе пример есть). Нет смысла её использовать при добавлении фильтра.
Покажите, как выводите контент в результате работы проблемного плагина. Тогда, возможно, будет проще подсказать.

Comment: вверху описал вывод контента файлов

Comment: **Если я, конечно, Вас правильно понял**, то `$before_content` это переменная, которая содержит уже полностью готовый контент предназначенный для вывода. В таком случае попробуйте `echo do_shortcode($before_content)`

Comment: отыскал. был в это куске файла vc_mad_blog_posts.php (добавил шорткод) `<?php echo (!empty($post_content)) ? "<p class='entry-body'>".do_shortcode($post_content)."</p>" : '' ?>` вопрос решен!